# You must have installed GD library with --with-jpeg-dir=DIR option

Tags: magento2, php-7

> **PHP Settings Check**
>
> **You must have installed GD library with --with-jpeg-dir=DIR option.**

**Getting the issue when I install Magento**

Answer (score 6):

**Need to install GD library**

Run the below command on cmd

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-gd 
sudo service apache2 restart
```

change php7.1 according to your current php version